# Opencv throwing errors while comparing two fingerprint images

Tags: python, opencv

i have a python function that is meant to compare two fingerprint images like this

```
import os
import cv2


def isIdentical():
    best_score = 0
    filename = None
    image = None
    kp1, kp2, mp = None, None, None

    finger_print_one = cv2.imread("compare/image1.jpg")
    finger_print_two = cv2.imread("compare/image2.jpg")

    resized_1 = cv2.resize(finger_print_one, None, fx=4, fy=4)
    resized_2 = cv2.resize(finger_print_two, None, fx=4, fy=4)

    sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

    keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(resized_1, None)
    keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(resized_2, None)

    matches = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher({'algorithm': 1, 'trees': 10}, {}).knnMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, k=2)
    match_points = []

    for p, q in matches:
        if p.distance < 0.1 * q.distance:
            match_points.append(p)

    keypoints = 0

    if len(keypoints_1) < len(keypoints_2):
        keypoints = len(keypoints_1)
    else:
        keypoints = len(keypoints_2)

    if len(match_points) / keypoints * 100 > best_score:
        best_score = len(match_points) / keypoints * 100
        image = resized_2
        kp1, kp2, mp = keypoints_1, keypoints_2, match_points

    print("SCORE: " + str(best_score))
    if len(match_points) > 0:
        result = cv2.drawMatches(resized_1, kp1, image, kp2, mp, None)
        result = cv2.resize(result, None, fx=4, fy=4)
        cv2.imshow("Result", result)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


#
# one = ""
isIdentical()
```

when the images are the same, the functions returns a `best_score` of 100, but when they are different images of the same fingerprint, the `best_score` is 0 and the `match_points` array is empty

for example when the inputs are like this

```
finger_print_one = cv2.imread("compare/image1.jpg")
finger_print_two = cv2.imread("compare/image1.jpg")
```

the `best_score` is `100`

but for

```
finger_print_one = cv2.imread("compare/image1.jpg")
finger_print_two = cv2.imread("compare/image2.jpg")
```

the `best_score` is `0` and the `match_points` is empty

is there anything i am missing?

Comment: In which line are you facing this error? The error says there is no image passed as input. Check whether image file path is correct. Check whether `finger_print_one` and `finger_print_two` are arrays

Comment: `finger_print_one` and `finger_print_2` are arrays. and they are the same fingerprint. the error is thrown on this line `result = cv2.drawMatches(resized_1, kp1, image, kp2, mp, None)`

Comment: when i use the same image like this  ```finger_print_one = cv2.imread("compare/emekaz.jpg")
    finger_print_two = cv2.imread("compare/emekascopy.jpg")``` no error is thrown and the score is 100

Comment: The variable `image` is `None`, because it does not satisfy the `if` condition. Before executing `cv2.drawMatches()` check the value of `image`

Comment: as JeruLuke said, check your second `if` statement. You've initially set `image = None`, what would happen if the second `if` fails ? `result = cv2.drawMatches(resized_1, kp1, image, kp2, mp, None)` will throw error.

Comment: i have been able to resolve the issue with the error but the function still returns a match score of `0` for two images of the same fingerprint

Comment: @LawrenceNwoko that is because there are no matches between the 2 images. Can you share the images?

Comment: https://res.cloudinary.com/onpointdeveloper/image/upload/v1654620893/emekaz.jpg


https://res.cloudinary.com/onpointdeveloper/image/upload/v1654620893/emekas.jpg

@JeruLuke these are two of the test images

Comment: @LawrenceNwoko looking at those images I doubt you will get any match at all. Both the images need to have some resemblance at least

Comment: @JeruLuke both images are  prints from the same finger what I want to match are finger the same finger prints the same image

Comment: @LawrenceNwoko You know that and I know it too. But the algorithm does not. Its because it is unable to find any realistic matches between the 2 images. I would like to see what the others say about this :)

Comment: @JeruLuke even if I change the dimensions a of the same image it fails.

Comment: You might need to threshold the fingerprints to b/w. If you cannot do that and get similar corner features, then they will not likely match. SIFT is looking generally for corners (intersections) at different resolutions.

Comment: @fmw42 how can i achieve this.

Comment: @fmw42 still waiting for you response.

Comment: Achieve what?  My suggestion was to try to threshold your images to see if the lines would be more distinct. Then do your feature matching on the thresholded images. If you do not know about thresholding, then do some research. Google it. Look into the OpenCV documentation for cv2.threshold() and cv2.inRange(). SIFT looks for corners or intersections. If you do not have such features in your images and lots of them, then your approach may not work well.  Also see the comment by @Jeru Luke above. You have not even provided example images. So it will be hard to make any suggestions.

Comment: @fmw42 Two images have been provided in the comments. But they look very different. It would be hard to find matches.

Comment: @Jeru Luke Thanks for point out the images. Those will be very hard to threshold and make any sense of. Off the top of my head, I do not see any easy way to process them for SIFT to find features. Why were they recorder on dark paper (background color)?  That makes it even harder. I know little about finger print matching. I suggest that more research is needed to find out how any matching is properly done. They likely look for larger features than just intersections. They likely look at swirls and other kinds of features. But the prints need to be more distinct!